# Raspberry Pi 4 b+ with SIM900A Module Error

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, serial, python-3, gsm

I'm working on a project that includes send a SMS message. I have tried connecting my raspberry pi with sim900a. Having problems with communication with sim. I've tried using AT commands with minicom with no success on communication. I've tried with this command:

> sudo minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyS0
> [image: Ssh connection with raspberry]

I have no luck with any commands showing up. My connection with the module is like this:
[image]

As usual connecting to TX->Rx, Rx->Tx (GPIO14, GPIO15 in Rpi) - following diagram from this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=louSyBRkvO4&t=4s
Any Help? Please

Comment: Don't post text as pictures, post error messages as text. Don't post diagrams as videos: take a screenshot with the diagram or draw it. And please switch the language in your terminal or system to English before logging error messages.

Comment: And I really have doubts that the jumper wires can supply the GSM module which may require up to 2A of current.

Comment: Have you connected GND to GND ?

Answer (score 0):

Log back into the RPi, and install minicom

```
sudo apt install minicom
```

Now to open minicom and connect.

Depending on your version of RPi, I connect to ttyAMA0.

On RPi4 I could connect using ttyS0 instead, so if ttyAMA0 freezes minicom, then try ttyS0

```
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 115200
```

or

```
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyS0 -b 115200
```

Answer (score 0):

I am searching forums about RPi and sim900a module issues.  Did your GSM module worked when interfaced with RPi? I am experiencing the same dilemma, no activities in the AT commands when RPi and GSM communication module has been interfaced.  Any suggestions for this.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/135803)